# Implement siblings() in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do in vanilla js what the siblings() does in jQuery. I've seen a lot of helpful explanations here but I'm having trouble implementing them on my code.

I have a div that has 4 buttons inside it. Every time i click on a button a class (.btn-anim) is added to that button (this works ok so far). What I want to do is when I click on one of the buttons (that doesn't have the class already) to remove the class of any other button and add it to the clicked one.

My Html markup:

```
<div id="js-colors-div">
  <button class="yellow"></button>
  <button class="green"></button>
  <button class="blue"></button>
  <button class="pink"></button>
</div>
```

And Js:

```
var colorsDiv = document.getElementById('js-colors-div'); 
var colors = colorsDiv.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {                   
    colors[i].onclick = function(e) {                                

    var highlight = e.target;

    //trying to achieve this         
    $(this).addClass('btn-anim').siblings().removeClass('btn-anim');          

    }
};
```

And this is my code for adding the class

```
highlight.classList.add('btn-anim'); //
```

Comment: Loop over the elements in `colors`. If it is the clicked button add `btn-anim`, else remove it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In vanilla JS you could loop over the parent's children and just skip the element itself. You can use `classList` methods for adding/removing the class:

```
    this.classList.add('btn-anim');
    for (let sibling of this.parentNode.children) {
        if (sibling !== this) sibling.classList.remove('btn-anim');
    }
```

Note however that you can (also in jQuery) simplify a bit: just remove the class from all buttons, and then add it to the current one:

```
    for (let sibling of this.parentNode.children) {
        sibling.classList.remove('btn-anim');
    }
    this.classList.add('btn-anim');
```

Comment: While this works with the OP, remember that siblings (parentNode.children) can be any other HTML element node. So classes would be added or removed from those nodes too. The jQuery siblings( ) function with an additional selector arguments needs then to be used.

Comment: @HerbertPeters, sure, but here the asker needs to *remove* styling from siblings, and only add styling to the already identified element. If some siblings need to *keep* this particular style (other than the selected element), then with vanilla JS (avoiding jQuery) you can still apply a selector, notably using `querySelectorAll` with `:scope >`. This has been covered in the [answer by Dylan Maxey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62643994/5459839). Please upvote their answer, as this addresses your concerns.

Answer (score 2):

.siblings() in jQuery also allows you to use a selector argument to target specific siblings and I don't think that's been addressed.

```
const getSiblings = (el, sel) => {
    const siblings = [];
    let targets;
    if (sel)
        targets = el.parentNode.querySelectorAll(':scope > ' + sel)
    else
        targets = el.parentNode.children;

    for (const target of targets) {
        if (target !== el)
            siblings.push(target);
    }
    return siblings;
};
```

Then this could be used like so for the OP's use case...

```
const removeAnimClass = (ev) => {
    const siblings = getSiblings(ev.currentTarget, '.btn-anim');
    for (const sibling of siblings) {
        sibling.classList.remove('btn-anim');
};

const colorsDiv = document.getElementById('js-colors-div'); 
const colorBtns = colorsDiv.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (const colorBtn of colorBtns) {                   
    colorBtn.onclick = removeAnimClass;
}
```

Comment: Great stuff! Note for others: Browser compatibility for :scope is non IE and from Safari 7. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope#browser_compatibility

Comment: `getSiblings` has one big drawback - it will work correctly only if the passed `sel` matches only the siblings (and `el` itself) and not their children because if the children of the siblings are returned then the filtering in the `for` loop will not work. In the end we might get the descendants of the `el` itself.

Comment: Not true. With the use of `:scope` and the direct child selector, you will only get the siblings, none of the children. See this demo https://codepen.io/dylan9o4/pen/KKRKQpm

Answer (score 1):

You can use `previousElementSibling` and `nextElementSibling` elements.

```js
var colorsDiv = document.getElementById('js-colors-div');
var colors = colorsDiv.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  colors[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var highlight = e.target;

    //trying to achieve this         
    this.classList.add('btn-anim');
    addClassSiblings.bind(this, 'btn-anim')();
  });
}

function addClassSiblings(classNames) {
  var cs = this.nextElementSibling;
  while(cs) {
    cs.classList.remove(classNames);
    cs = cs.nextElementSibling;
  }
  
  cs = this.previousElementSibling;
  while(cs) {
    cs.classList.remove(classNames);
    cs = cs.previousElementSibling;
  }
}
```

```css
.yellow {
  color: yellow
}

.pink {
  color: pink
}

.green {
  color: green
}

.blue {
  color: blue
}

.btn-anim {
  color: black
}
```

```html
<div id="js-colors-div">
  <button class="yellow">yellow</button>
  <button class="green">green</button>
  <button class="blue">blue</button>
  <button class="pink">pink</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const colorsDiv = document.getElementById('js-colors-div');
const children = [...colorsDiv.children];

children.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    children.forEach((btn) => {
      btn.classList.remove('active');
    })
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  color: white
}

.yellow {
  background: #ffaf00
}

.pink {
  background: pink
}

.green {
  background: green
}

.blue {
  background: blue
}

.active {
  background: black
}
```

```html
<div id="js-colors-div">
  <button class="yellow">yellow</button>
  <button class="green">green</button>
  <button class="blue">blue</button>
  <button class="pink">pink</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this, give all `buttons` the same `class` `(i.e .checked)`.

Next, create a loop and iterate over each `li DOM Element`.
Once inside the loop, create another loop that will, in turn, remove the class `.checked` from all elements, and then it will add only to the one you `clicked`.

```js
const rates = document.querySelectorAll(".rate");

for (const rate of rates) 
{
  rate.addEventListener("click", function () 
  {
    for (const i of rates) 
    {
      i.classList.remove("checked");
    }

    rate.classList.add("checked");
  });
}
```

```html
<ul class="rating-box">
 <li><button class="rate rate-1">1</button></li>
 <li><button class="rate rate-2">2</button></li>
 <li><button class="rate rate-3">3</button></li>
 <li><button class="rate rate-4">4</button></li>
 <li><button class="rate rate-5">5</button></li>
</ul>
```